# When words speak!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, steganography

Short Steganographic Riddle!

> Every time you ask me, where do you stay?
>   It's vague but I stay here, I will say.
>   We are three, you know it. Check if it fits your height.
>   3 elders of this riddle decide my name, begin from the right.
>   Let's add a couple of lines more, to add a little spice.
>   Wrapped around, not a killer, I am nice.
>   Riddle formed of many, though useful only a few
>   The master who decodes ingenious "3 Elders" factor, gets a new!
>   I will fill in two more lines, and say, I hide the twist and look straight,
>   By elder, I mean nothing, but the weight. Don't you get?

Find what is hidden up there!

Enjoy!

Hint

> X and Y are two people - X has lived for 10 years and Y for 15 years. Who is elder? Y right? Why? Because, he has lived 5 years longer than X. Similarly, a riddle is formed of _____ out of which 3 are the elders. Significant?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time wording this succinctly. My question is, if a solution or method would have worked with the original text but now doesn't make sense with the additions, does that mean it's not the right one?

Comment: There is only one solution. Version changes hasn't affected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a

> **TIE**

---

After I posted [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50146/terms-and-conditions-apply) I was told this was similar. So I tried

> Checking the letter frequencies for the entire riddle.

Now we have the line

> 3 elders of this riddle decide my name, begin from the right.

And

> By elder, I mean nothing, but the weight. Don't you get?

This is hinting at

> The three most occurring letters. Weight sort of cluing importance.

They are

> EIT

and 'starting from the right' gives the word

> TIE - just reverse it

There are also a couple of clues:

> Wrapped around, not a killer, I am nice.
>   I hide the twist and look straight,

Which fit the answer:

> A tie is wrapped around your neck, but it is not a noose, it doesn't kill you, it makes you look smart. It has a twist (knot) then a straight bit hanging down.

So you are a

> Tie

Comment: Nice work! +10 already added. Take +15 as well :-)

Comment: @Techidiot he :P Next time for these you might want to include a *slightly* more obvious clue for frequency analysis. Then someone might get it within the month! I probably should have made mine slightly more subtle too...

Comment: I had forgotten this puzzle until I solved yours. Thanks for reminding :-) And yeah, it could have been improved.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret "3 Elders" as

> 3 longest words. "Elder" here means more letters in the word. (It could also mean longest lines, and words in the line, but the [first revision](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/47517/1) of the question had only four lines, and longer lines have been added since, so that's unlikely.

*3 elders of this riddle decide my name, begin from the right.*

> The original version of the riddle had only this line and the 3 above it, so that should be enough to solve the riddle as originally intended. Take the longest word in each of the 3 lines above ("Every", "vague", "height"), and then take the rightmost letter of each one.

So the final answer might be the word

> YET.

Comment: Cool thought. +1 But the answer still is the same with all the version changes. Stretch your thought about the words a little more and you shall find it. The final word is described in the riddle as well. I mean - the riddle describes the word as well

Comment: @Techidiot To clarify, are you saying that the fact that new, longer words have been added and the answer hasn't changed, means that "elders" doesn't refer to the longest words?

Comment: Right. The elders doesnt refer to longer words. Else this could have been the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it…

> me?

Because…

> I "said my name".
>
>  "begin from the right" doesn't suit neither the rhyme size nor the rhyme itself. So we have "my name" and "say".
>
>  Also, three elders may mean Ego, Alter-Ego and Super-Ego.
>
>  As we are the one, we stay at different places, but still here, inside me, so our place is uncertain (vague)

Comment: Sorry. There is a stegano tag for a reason.